# Docker image displaying backend

Tags: node.js, docker

I made [this](https://github.com/tamaraltahan/NextStats) hobby project of a website which runs a next.js frontend and node/express backend. I'm working on getting this set up in a docker container so I can try hosting it with the following dockerfile (having never used docker before).

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000 3001

CMD ["yarn", "both"]
```

I have `both` as `"both": "npm-run-all -p dev server",` in my package.json file which I've been using to normally run my project with no problem.

When I run the image, I'm seeing the default response from my backend as the content of the webpage.

My frontend runs on port 3000, and my backend on 3001.

Comment: When you open it in your browser, are you hitting 3001 or 3000? (Or, which port are you proxying to from whatever might be in front of this?) And FWIW in prod it would be much more efficient to run `next build`, move the built files under the server dir, and serve them with `express.static`, rather than running the Next dev server.

Comment: @ZacAnger My browser opens on port 3000 which is correct, & trying localhost:3001 gives me the 'site can't be reached' error.

Comment: Do you map the ports on your `docker run` command? Is the backend bound to 0.0.0.0?